# bash: pass each command through time command (to measure execution time)

Tags: bash, shell, time

How to pass each command (typed in the shell) through `time` command?

Reason of the question: need to measure execution time of each command (without typing `time` each time).

Example (wanted behavior):

```
$ sleep 1
real    0m1.047s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176386/automatically-timing-every-executed-command-and-show-in-bash-prompt

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk, excellent! Thanks!